# Prove that for any $u, v \in R \times R \times R$, $Ru + Rv \neq R \times R \times R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be an integral domain and $F$ be the field of fractions of $R$. Let $\phi: R \times R \rightarrow R \times R \times R$ be an R-module homomorphism.Prove that for any $u, v \in R \times R \times R$, $Ru + Rv \neq R \times R \times R$.

My idea is that since R \times R \times R has dimension of 3. It cannot be generated by two elements. However, I find this to be to be deceptively easy. What am I misunderstanding here? Do I have to prove that R \times R \times R has dimension of 3? (Can I prove it this way, since $e_1, e_2, e_3$ generates $R \times R \times R$ and because if A, B are basis of $R \times R \times R$, then |A| = |B|, dimension of $R \times R \times R$ = 3.

Comment: @user26857 how to prove that $R^3$ is of rank 3?

Comment: Use the canonical basis.

Comment: which is the same idea of what i mention above right? if i can find a basis of dimension 3, so the other basis must be of dimension 3 too?

Comment: Yes. The rank is well defined for free modules over commutative rings. (What it's not so obvious is why $R^3$ can't be generated by two elements, but this can be done by using matrices.)

Comment: @user26857 i can't just say that since $R^3$ is dimension 3 so it can't be generated by 2 elements? Is this not obvious?

Comment: For vector spaces it is, but not for free modules.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is equivalent to the property that there is no epimorphism from $R\times R$ to $R\times R\times R$. (hint for the latter: by Nakayama's Lemma, all epimorphisms from $R\times R\times R$ to $R\times R\times R$ is isomorphisms.)

Comment: Since $R$ is a domain, just use the field of fractions and vector spaces.